# Como iniciar um ConsoleApplication que gere todos os objetos do banco igual ao CodeFirst

Tags: c#, design-pattern, projeto-de-software, automatização

Ola! a Todos

Estou iniciando um projeto em Console Application em C#, tenho lido muito sobre Entity Framework, Code First, Migrations.

A finalidade deste projeto é gerar todas as tabelas de um schema de banco de dados em Data Models, peço a ajuda de vocês para isso. Minha duvida é a seguinte! abaixo:

Eu quero fazer o mesmo que o Add-in do Visual Studio chamado 'Code First' faz porem eu quero gerar os modelos (Model Domain, Model Dto, Model Service) em caminhos diferentes, a ideia deste gerador é automatizar a geração destes Modelos.

Alguém perguntaria por que não usar o Code First tals, pois então, o Code First gera tudo que eu preciso mas eu quero com nomenclaturas que eu possa colocar ao gerar o objeto entendem ex:

Base de Dados

- ad_escola
- ad_pessoa
- ad_aluno
- ad_professor

Baseado nas tabelas quero gerar organizadamente

Camada de Dados (sera um Projeto Windows Library).

- Escola.cs
- EscolaMapper.cs
- Pessoa.cs
- PessoaMapper.cs
- Aluno.cs
- AlunoMapper.cs
- Professor.cs
- ProfessorMapper.cs

Camada de Domain (sera um Projeto Windows Library) já com métodos Add, Get, Edit, etc.

- Escola.cs
- Pessoa.cs
- Aluno.cs
- Professor.cs

Camada de Dto (sera um Projeto Windows Library).

- EscolaDto.cs
- PessoaDto.cs
- AlunoDto.cs
- ProfessorDto.cs

Camada de Service (sera um Projeto Windows Library) que retorna os objetos já montados pelo Domain, ela irá comunicar-se com Front End ou Camada de Apresentação.

- EscolaSevice.cs
- PessoaSevice.cs
- AlunoSevice.cs
- ProfessorSevice.cs

Detalhes, esse gerador poderei usar em qualquer fase do projeto, se eu criar uma tabela nova no projeto, usarei ele para gerar os Modelos dessa nova tabela do banco.
Minha duvida é como posso pegar todas as tabelas do banco e gerar isso de de uma forma inicial bem simples.

Para mais informações criei um projeto no GitHub quem quiser ajudar a desenvolver é só
falar comigo, e trabalhamos juntos e o Gerador de Código, ficará para todos aqueles que ajudarem, é uma ótima ideia no meu ponto de vista.

A principio queria fazer ele enxergar 3 principais bancos de dados hoje comuns:

- SQLServer
- Oracle
- MySql

Dados do GitHub

- Link: https://github.com/rodrigoarf/Gerador
- Software do GitHub: https://windows.github.com/

Aqueles que quiserem ajudar a desenvolver este pequeno projeto, falem comigo e me passem o usuário do GitHub pois adicionarei como "Contributor from Project", ai vocês podem desenvolver e dar Commit e no Repositorio do GitHup sempre terá a ultima versão atualizada para todos aqueles que contribuírem.

Aguardo dicas, sugestões de toda a comunidade.
Abraços.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto já existe. Chama [ASP.NET MvcScaffolding](https://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), mas o projeto foi abandonado porque a Microsoft abandonou o suporte ao DTE no Visual Studio 2013, privilegiando a geração pelos menus de contexto do Visual Studio.

Outra coisa que pode ser interessante para o seu projeto é o [SideWaffle, gerador de templates para extensões para o Visual Studio](http://sidewaffle.com/). Pode até ser mais interessante do que chamar os comandos por console.

---

**UPDATE**

Apenas ventilando o que eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119731/o-que-%c3%a9-scaffold/119751?s=1|0.3480#119751) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101516/o-que-mudou-do-mvc4-para-mvc5/101536?s=2|0.2541#101536), o [MvcScaffolding foi atualizado para o VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/1.0.10). A versão mais recente é para VS2015 e VS2013. Apenas use a versão mais recente se tiver os dois Visual Studio, senão use a versão 1.0.10 travada no arquivo `packages.config` da seguinte forma:

```
<packages>
    <package id="MvcScaffolding.VS2015" version="1.0.10" targetFramework="net452" allowedVersions="[1.0.10]" />
    <package id="T4Scaffolding.Core.VS2015" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" allowedVersions="[1.0.1]" />
    <package id="T4Scaffolding.VS2015" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net452" allowedVersions="[1.0.8]" />
</packages>
```