# O que mudou do MVC4 para MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Eu já li alguns tópicos sobre o assunto, uns dizem que mudou bem pouco, outros dizem que foram mudanças muito importantes. Gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês referente ao assunto, atualmente faço projetos com WebForms então não possuo conhecimentos sobre MVC, e comprei um livro MVC4, esse migração me preocupa um pouco.

Comment: Olha, para você aprender o básico é só estudar MVC, entenda a arquitetura, faça um CRUD, jogue dados básico pra lá e pra cá, use objetos depois, etc. Com isso você vai entender a arquitetura MVC, Hoje já existe o MVC6, nesse já teva mais alterações ainda. Não sei tudo que mudou, mas eu acho que vale você ler alguns blogs sobre isso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe uma [página oficial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) dizendo quais foram as novidades, não precisa se valer de opiniões que nem são aceitas aqui. Essencialmente tudo o que aprender no 4 pode ser aproveitado no 5. Há mudanças importantes também nas versões subsequentes, [5.1](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), [5.2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-mvc-52?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se só quer saber se o livro está perdido ou não, é claro que não. Mas aprender com material mais novo é sempre melhor. O importante é aprender tudo corretamente.

Na verdade se vai começar, eu pensaria no [ASP.NET Core](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/index.html?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Este teve mudanças mais importantes. Ele é o futuro, vale investir nele. As versões anteriores são consideradas legado.

Comment: Então @bigown é que atualmente não tem tradução em português para o livros mvc5, muito menos para o 6. Acabei achando esse livro:
"Desenvolvimento web com ASP.NET MVC (Versão 4) - casadocodigo"
Então não sei se compensou eu ter comprado ele, afinal você disse que era melhor eu aprender diretamente no 6.

Comment: Compensar, compensa. Se não sabe inglês e não tem nada melhor, é o que dá para usar. Particularmente não costumo gostar dos livros em português, é muito raro ter algum bom. Não conheço esse, mas deve quebrar um galho para quem não sabe nada sobre o assunto. Só espero que ele não ensine fazer coisas erradas, como acontece com alguns livros. Você pode começar com uma versão mais velha mas depois provavelmente vai querer aprender as mais novas. Se não tiver material, você vai ficar parado?

Answer (score 8):

Em resumo, muita coisa.

Detalhando um pouco mais, as mudanças mais importantes são:

- *Scaffolds* atualizados para suportar o Bootstrap, que vem instalado por padrão para projetos novos;
- Recurso de *Scaffolding* passa a ser nativo do Visual Studio, com suporte a transações assíncronas, recurso novo do Entity Framework 6, ORM padrão do ASP.NET MVC. Antigamente o *Scaffolding* era feito apenas pelo [MvcScaffolding](http://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-scaffolding-aprendendo-a-usar-o-pacote/30242), mas Mr. Sanderson achou por bem abandonar o projeto e deixou um bocado de gente na mão. Recentemente, um bacana chamado [David Douglas Anderson](https://github.com/processedbeets) [retomou o projeto, para a felicidade de todos](https://github.com/processedbeets/ASP.NET-MVC-Scaffolding), então agora a comunidade tem as duas opções de *Scaffolding*, sendo a por linha de comando a mais poderosa;
- Depreciação do ASP.NET Membership e introdução do ASP.NET Identity, mais abrangente e com suporte a autenticação de dois fatores (confirmação por SMS ou e-mail, por exemplo), integração com provedores de OAuth conhecidos (Facebook, Google+, Twitter, etc.) e possibilidades maiores de customização dessa autenticação;
- Grande atualização do [HtmlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) e todas as suas extensões ([LinkExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions_methods(v=vs.118).aspx), [SelectExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions(v=vs.118).aspx), [InputExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions(v=vs.118).aspx), [EditorExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx), [InputExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx), etc.);
- Introdução do [OWIN](http://owin.org/), nova especificação de interface que irá reger todas as versões do ASP.NET MVC de agora em diante;
- Descentralização da inicialização do ambiente global, antes feito apenas pelo `Global.asax.cs`, agora feito por classes parciais denominadas [`Startup`](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection);
- Opção de escrita de [rotas por atributo em cada *Action*](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-mvc-5-attribute-routing);
- Web API 2 passa a ser um padrão de projeto embarcado no Visual Studio versões 2012 e 2013;

Até a data desta resposta, o ASP.NET MVC5 ainda é a versão estável (ASP.NET 5 e MVC6 ainda são *release candidates*), mas, [conforme a resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101521/2999), já vale a pena ir direto para ele nesta altura do campeonato, até porque falta muito pouco para que a versão do MVC6 se torne estável.

Algumas mudanças são bastante profundas, e já posso falar de algumas delas:

- O compilador .NET passa a ser independente de plataforma (funcionando até em Mac e Linux);
- O Visual Studio deixa de ser a única IDE oficial (há também o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), independente de plataforma);
- No MVC5, não é possível aproveitar (pelo menos não sem alguma refatoração grande) a lógica de um *Controller* entre uma aplicação MVC e uma aplicação Web API 2 porque as implementações de cada estrutura de *Controller* são muito diferentes entre elas. Isto deve acabar no ASP.NET 5 e MVC6;
- IoC e DI passam a ser padrões de projeto. Até o MVC5, é possível usar IoC e DI, mas através de pacotes de terceiros e alguma configuração;
- O NuGet deixa de ser a única plataforma suportada de pacotes. Estão garantidos suporte a Bower, Grunt e npm;
- O *Scaffolding* passa a ser feito usando Yeoman, e não mais a IDE do Visual Studio.

> Possivelmente vou ter que editar essa resposta umas várias vezes, até porque o MVC6 vai estabilizar em breve. Peço a todos que me lembrem quando alguma coisa defasar ou se esqueci algum detalhe importante, pra que eu possa melhorar ainda mais esta resposta.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado ajudou bastante, algumas coisas eu ja sabia mas ajudou, as duas respostas foram claras e suficientes, obrigado novamente, abraço!