# O que é scaffold?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, scaffold

Comecei a estudar ASP.NET MVC e me deparei com o termo *scaffold*, mas não entendi muito bem, então:

1. O que é *scaffold*?
2. Qual sua utilização dentro do ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## O que é Scaffold?

[Scaffold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming)) é uma técnica antiquíssima de geração de código baseado em gabaritos de operações comuns que costumam ser usadas em aplicações diferentes.

Ao contrário do que muita gente acredita, provavelmente fruto de ter aprendido por receita de bolo, existem várias técnicas para obter o resultado final.

É possível realizar isto em tempo de execução ou em tempo de desenvolvimento, gerando códigos fontes que são agregados ao projeto como se fossem escritos por uma pessoa.

Esta técnica usa uma especificação em algum lugar para gerar todo o código necessário baseado em gabaritos de código preestabelecidos em algum lugar. Esta especificação pode ser direta ou indiretamente obtidas do banco de dados, das classes do modelo ou outra forma (um arquivo XML/JSON ou formato especifico auxiliar ou mesmo um banco com um **dicionário de dados**<sup>*</sup>, por exemplo). O resto é gerado pela ferramenta de *scaffolding*.

A técnica é mais bem empregada quando este mesmo dado é usado em vários pontos do código, mas mesmo em outras situações ele pode ser útil, inclusive gerando códigos para alguns padrões de projeto mais conhecidos.

Também, ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, ele não é só usado para fazer CRUD, ainda que seja em um ponto onde a técnica seja bem empregada.

A ferramenta é uma ótima auxiliar para obter o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Com o C# 7 e o Visual Studio 15 iniciaram incentivos às técnicas de *scaffolding*. E no C# 9/10 deve ter mais ainda com a adição de [Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (ainda que seja usado para algo além de *scaffold*.

## Uso com MVC

O [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) é um padrão de projeto que propõe a criação de 3 camadas, principalmente o modelo e a visão **normalmente** estão fortemente ligadas ao conteúdo do banco de dados. Ou seja, as colunas do banco de dados são os membros de uma classe do modelo e serão os controles da tela na visão. Há uma relação de um para um. É óbvio que não faz sentido você ter cada uma destas partes dissonantes entre si. E é claro também que o MVC não precisa necessariamente usar um *database* como fonte de dados, isto depende da ferramenta utilizada. a estrutura do banco de dados pode até mesmo ser gerada pela ferramenta de *scaffolding*.

Em alguns casos o controlador pode ter alguma coisa bem padronizada, principalmente quando se trata de [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete). E isto pode ser gerado pela ferramenta de *scaffold*, em alguns casos aproveitando a mesma fonte de dados das demais partes.

Então no MVC você tem pelo menos 3 locais, ou mais, com código bem burocrático, que podemos chamar de [*boilerplate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code), que se repete em todas as aplicações só variando os "campos" que serão utilizados. Sua estrutura básica é a mesma, não importa em que linguagem, que tipo de aplicação, padrão de projeto ou tecnologia que está sendo aplicado.

Normalmente sempre preferi a geração feita em tempo de execução, até pelo tipo de aplicação que costumo trabalhar, mas para o ASP.NET MVC vejo mais comum a geração durante o desenvolvimento, e ultimamente tenho visto algum valor nisto.

## ASP.NET MVC

É possível adotar várias ferramentas de *scaffolding* com o ASP.NET MVC. Pode-se criar a sua própria, mas a maioria usa a ferramenta pronta mais atual disponibilizada pela Microsoft.

O ASP.NET MVC já possui boas [ferramentas integradas com o Visual Studio](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview) e permite bastante [personalização](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/asp-net-mvc-override-the-default-scaffold-templates?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Em geral elas funcionam melhor com Entity Framework usando o modelo como especificação para o resto. Lembrando que o modelo pode ser gerado usando como base o banco de dados, conforme confirma outra resposta, contradizendo os comentários que geraram negativos na minha resposta. Cito especificamente o trecho "pode ser qualquer outro elemento que alimente a cadeia de geração de código" e complemento que um desses elementos é o banco de dados, mesmo que isto seja feita de forma indireta.

Como a ferramenta utiliza pelo ASP.NET MVC é integrada com o EF ela pode gerar os códigos (incluindo SQL) necessários para manter o banco de dados em sincronia com a aplicação.

Então a ferramenta mantém a sincronia entre DB-Model-View (HTML/JS).

Toda esta descrição e liberdade de fonte de dados da especificação e de resultado final fica ainda mais evidente com a ferramenta moderna de *scaffolding* [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/). Certamente o tempo fará ela abrir a mente de quem está acostumado com apenas uma ferramenta de *scaffolding*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

---

<sup>*</sup>[Dicionário de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/347190/101) é algo existente há décadas, mas que não pegou tração no mercado. Como tudo que não é muito falado é ignorado pela imensa maioria da pessoas. Esta é um ferramenta poderosíssima para documentar de forma ativa o que o software trabalha e principalmente subsidiar a automação da criação de códigos, justamente o *scaffolding*. Se isto fosse melhor divulgado haveria um ganho de produtividade enorme para muita gente, abrindo uma janela de oportunidades e nova forma de desenvolvimento de software evitando o trabalho burocrático que toma a maior parte do tempo dos programadores. Por isso eu reforço que é preciso ser criativo, buscar o que não é *mainstream*, pensar fora da caixa e olhar a experiência dos outros ao invés de apenas seguir o fluxo, olhar apenas para ferramentas já existentes e repetir o que todo mundo está fazendo sem questionamentos.

Comment: Uma biblioteca chamada `Way Generator` é responsável pelo `scaffold` do `Laravel` :D +1

Comment: A visão não está fortemente ligada ao banco de dados. O que acontece no ASP.NET MVC é que o modelo é usado para gerar as visões em algumas operações pré-definidas. As definições de geração dos clichês não são obtidas do banco de dados. O *scaffolding* gera, inclusive, o passo incremental do banco de dados, chamado de *Migration*.

Comment: Pra mim isto que você descreveu é estar ligado ao banco de dados. Eu não disse que a visão se comunica com o banco de dados, apenas que a visão é gerada baseada nas mesmas informações do modelo e do banco de dados. A visão é a "tela" dos dados, ela não é algo que aparece do nada sem nenhum vínculo com o banco de dados, você não cria uma visão para uma tabela de cliente colocando ali informações de de uma nota fiscal. Indiretamente pode ser obtido do banco de dados.

Comment: Continua errado. O *Scaffolding* não se comunica com o banco de dados para gerar visões. A geração é inteira *offline*. Se eu gerar uma visão a partir de um *ViewModel*, consigo.

Comment: Eu não disse isso, mas tem horas que você se apega a uma coisa e não larga, então não vai gerar nada produtivo aqui, não adianta eu ficar argumentando. Na verdade sua resposta confirma o que eu disse.

Comment: "Por isso eu reforço que é preciso ser criativo, buscar o que não é mainstream" Onde eu poderia encontrar conteúdos voltados ao que estaria no "underground"? Seguindo a sua visão, conhecer o scaffold me despertou mais interesse em busca do que esta por fora das receitas ou o que nem chegamos(eu) a se quer ouvir, mas que estao ai para complementar fortemente. Nao fazia ideia da existencia do scaffold, é realmente interessante.@bigown

Comment: @Marcial não tem muito isso, são coisas que vai pesquisando, estudando, tentando. O que não pode é se conformar e ficar achando que sabe tudo porque viu o que todo mundo está falando. As coisas vão cruzando o caminho se tiver uma atitude aberta. Um pouco de sorte ajuda. Mas tem gente que tem sorte e a dispensa por se manter fechado a uma visão única.

Comment: Tentando acrescentar algo, existe a spec MDA criada pela OMG a bastante tempo mais de 10 anos que tentou ate padronizar algo do tipo com uma linguagem que pudesse definir metamodelos em UML e gerar sistemas a partir disso usando cartuchos especificos por plataforma como no abandonado AndroMDA. Onde você poderia modelar um sistema com UML apertar o play e escolher um cartucho .NET ou Java por exemplo e sair um sistema praticamente pronto implementado com MVC a partir disso com uso de esteriotipos no modelo que seriam interpretadados, algo proximo de um JHipster d hje.Na epoca nao deu mto certo.

Answer (score 37):

> O que é?

*Scaffold* é um pré-moldado. O termo vem emprestado da construção civil. A técnica de conversão do *Scaffold* em um elemento da arquitetura ASP.NET MVC é chamado de *Scaffolding*.

> Qual sua utilização dentro do asp.net mvc?

Ser um facilitador de desenvolvimento, gerando estruturas que se repetem muitas vezes no sistema de uma maneira rápida e simples.

O ponto de partida para esta geração normalmente é um *Model*, mas pode ser qualquer outro elemento que alimente a cadeia de geração de código, como por exemplo um arquivo de configuração. O *Scaffolding* nativo passou a ser padrão no Visual Studio 2013, aposentando indevidamente o outro mecanismo, conhecido como MVcScaffolding, porque, segundo a Microsoft, o MvcScaffolding não seguia o padrão de usabilidade desejado pela Microsoft.

No ano passado (da data desta resposta), me juntei ao [David Douglas Anderson](https://github.com/processedbeets) para [fazer o MvcScaffolding voltar a funcionar nas versões do Visual Studio 2013 e 2015](https://github.com/processedbeets/ASP.NET-MVC-Scaffolding). Portanto, há as opções de geração de código clichê tanto pela interface do Visual Studio quanto por linha de comando.

Em projetos ASP.NET MVC, o *Scaffolding* possibilita a geração de CRUD's, a geração de passos incrementais de banco de dados (em uso conjunto com o Entity Framework, chamados de *Migrations*) e a automatização de algumas tarefas, como adicionar linhas de configuração ou atualizar trechos de código com alguma estruturação, como, por exemplo, adicionar um novo elemento no contexto de dados (novamente falando de Entity Framework). Há ainda a possibilidade de usar *Scaffolding* para geração de elementos JavaScript, em caso de telas típicas de SPA.

A abordagem de *Scaffolding* será inteiramente remodelada a partir do ASP.NET Core 1.0, em que está previsa a aposentadoria do *Scaffolding* nativo e MvcScaffolding, [dando preferência ao Yeoman](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet).

Answer (score 22):

O [MvcScaffolding](http://www.macoratti.net/13/04/mv4_scf2.htm) é um pacote para ASP.NET que é instalado via `NuGet` usando o comando `MvcScaffolding Install-Package` e que permite criar de forma automática a estrutura completa para controladores e views.

De modo geral, o *scaffold* permite criar um rápido esqueleto funcional para o seu sistema em prol da alta produtividade.

Na verdade, trata-se de um conceito, também utilizado em outras linguagens, como Ruby, Python e Grails.

Answer (score 10):

As explicações acima foram bem completas sobre o que é scaffolding e sua utilização. Vou descrever abaixo como utilizâ-lo na prática. Só para contextualizar a minha explanação, toda vez que é criado um controller e views, o scaffolding utiliza templates que geram o controller e suas views (crud). Portanto, em projetos que tenho muitas tabelas eu importo e modifico os templates para me dar mais agilidade, exemplo: troco os termos em inglês para português, adiciono bibliotecas, filtros, novos métodos, nova estrutura de determinada view, etc.

1) Vai até a pasta de templates da instalação do seu visual studio, no meu caso é o visual studio 2015 e está no endereço:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2) Crie a pasta "CodeTemplates" no seu projeto e importe os templates que deseja customizar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3) Em seguida edite os templates do controller ou das views que deseja modificar de acordo com a linguagem que utilza, no caso, coloquei templates somente em ".cs". No exemplo abaixo estou incluindo uma linha abaixo do namespace do controller: "[Authorize(Roles = "Administrador")]" para que toda vez que criar um controller tenha esta instrução. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto, agora é só criar um novo controller que esteja de acordo com o template que modificou que o scaffolding irá gerar os códigos com as alterações realizadas.

Comment: Senti falta do plugin da Tangible aí, para o Highlight dos T4: http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html