# É uma má ideia versionarmos classes geradas automaticamente com JiBX?

Tags: java, scaffold

Onde trabalho temos um projeto (bem velho) que utiliza JiBX para gerar algumas classes a partir de *schemas*. Essas classes são geradas no build logo os *source* não existem no projeto.

Alguém deu a brilhante ideia de pegar esses *source* gerados e colocar (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) dentro do projeto, assim não seria mais necessário gerar elas e somente quando tivermos alguma alteração nos *schema*.

Isso não me parece uma boa ideia, já que as classes geradas são muito ruins e isso abriria margem para que alguém alterassem elas, gerando uma versão que poderá ser incompatível com os *schemas*.

Quais argumentos posso utilizar para convencer o time que isso não é uma boa ideia (se realmente não for)?

Comment: 1. Defina boa prática; 2. Simplesmente explique pra eles o porquê disto não ser uma boa ideia, se você não souber, provavelmente seja uma boa ideia.

Comment: "má prática" foi uma péssima escolha

Comment: @ElizeuBorges Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu, particularmente, vejo alguns motivos para considerar que isso **não** é uma boa ideia:

- Quanto menos código melhor. Frameworks existem exatamente para que não tenhamos que criar códigos e mais códigos se alguém (ou algo) pode fazer isso pra a gente :P
- A partir do momento que você assume a criação de um código, bom, o código vira seu. Em outros termos, você é 100% responsável por garantir que este esteja funcional e sem bugs.
- CTRL + C e CTRL + V? Sério mesmo? Normalmente códigos gerados por frameworks/libs são códigos "feios". Se querem realmente colocar dentro da pasta `src` pelo menos façam uma implementação original/melhor, né?
- Quanto menos código você mantém menor é o tamanho do seu repositório
- Quanto menos código você mantém menos teste você precisa ter/executar
- Se você usa alguma ferramenta de analise estática de código (o [Sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/), por exemplo), você pode desconsiderar os códigos gerados pela lib, uma vez que de fato não são da sua equipe.

Answer (score 4):

Entendi que essa ferramenta, que não conheço, gera código ruim, e por isso mesmo deveria procurar outra solução.

Deve existir um motivo para serem geradas no *build* e não deixar disponível no projeto e é justamente **não deixar mexer nele**. Mais ainda, é provável que a mudança ocorra com frequência, então **mexer no código não faz sentido**, vai perder tudo ou no próximo *build*, ou quando precisar uma mudança. Esses **códigos gerados são feitos para não mexer**.

Subverter isso parece bastante falta de bom senso. Se não confia na ferramenta, não a use. Sou favorável ao uso de [*scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101), mas precisa ser a ferramenta certa e usada da forma correta.

**Inverta a situação**. Tudo o que pode gerar um esforço deve ser justificado. Peça para eles argumentarem o porquê de fazer isso. Se for fazer por fazer não é um bom argumento. Se for para melhorar ou personalizar o código, já tem os argumentos contrários ditos acima. Se for outra coisa precisa procurar um motivo para contra-argumentar, mas eu acho que fica nesses dois que eu disse.

Boa ou má prática é argumento de quem não tem argumento. Não precisa existir uma má prática, precisa existir um bom motivo para fazer algo e ele não pode trazer prejuízos indesejáveis. Tem que analisar tecnicamente. Má prática é evitar análise e assumir o que outra pessoa disse sem conhecer o seu contexto.

C# tem até classes parciais para que o código gerado antes do *build* faça parte do projeto e ao mesmo tempo fique protegido de mudanças, se tudo estiver bem estruturado.