# O que é a Arquitetura Baseada em Metadados (MDDA)?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software

O que é uma Arquitetura Baseada em Metadados?

Quando usar esse tipo de arquitetura?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma arquitetura que prega um nível de abstração tão alto que praticamente não há código. Há um *framework* que trabalha com metadados definidos para criar a aplicação. É uma forma declarativa de se criar uma aplicação, em oposição ao estilo imperativo de códigos que estamos acostumados. Também costuma ter alguma ferramenta que auxilie trabalhar com estes metadados.

Em geral usa-se uma técnica de [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) onde tudo o que o sistema precisa saber está em apenas um lugar, o metadado. E o [*scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101) é muito usado para gerar código. Há também softwares que se adaptam em *runtime*.

De maneira geral é pouco adotado porque os resultados não são tão bons quanto parece que seriam. Talvez um pouco pelas ferramentas existentes hoje, talvez porque as tecnologias adotadas não são as mais adequadas, talvez porque prometem mais que podem entregar, o que gera frustração.

Um exemplo é o [LightSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851953.aspx) da Microsoft que foi descontinuado devido a baixa adesão.

Eu gosto da ideia geral, mas não da maneira como usam. Um modelo híbrido pode funcionar melhor.

Comment: existe algum projeto ´Opensource` para dar uma olhada ?

Comment: @JcSaint desconheço alguma.