# Como fazer scaffold de uma base existente com Oracle.EntityframeworkCore sem usuário com superpoderes?

Tags: oracle, scaffold

Estou tentando fazer o [scaffold](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119731/o-que-%C3%A9-scaffold) de uma base Oracle com `Oracle.Entityframework.Core`, porém segundo esse link [dotnet-db-samples](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/tree/master/samples/dotnet-core/ef-core), são necessárias as seguintes permissões:

```
GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE,UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO blog IDENTIFIED BY blog;
ALTER USER blog DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS;
ALTER USER blog TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;
```

Acontece que o **DBA não me fornece** essas **permissões**.

São necessárias todas essas permissões? Existem uma maneira de que obtendo o acesso como dono do esquema não haja risco de prejudicar outros esquemas?